# Can I normalize nested data in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting data in stange formats that I cannot control but my system has to process them. Here's a example

```
json_2020 = '''{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "finance": [
                {
                    "type": "income",
                    "value": 100000
                },
                {
                    "type": "stock_market_profits",
                    "value": 5000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Alice",
            "finance": [
                {
                    "type": "income",
                    "value": 90000
                },
                {
                    "type": "real_estate_profits",
                    "value": 200000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'''

json_2021 = '''
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Alice",
            "finance": [
                {
                    "type": "income",
                    "value": 75000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "finance": [
                {
                    "type": "stock_market_profits",
                    "value": 7000
                },
                {
                    "type": "income",
                    "value": 90000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

'''
```

Assuming json_2020 and json_2021 come in at different times but through the same process, I'm not sure how to normalize them.

The outcome I want is something like this:

```
Name, Income, Stock_market_profits, real_estate_profits, year
Bob, 100000, 5000, null, 2020
Alice, 90000, null, 200000, 2020
Alice, 75000, null, null, 2021
Bob, 90000, 7000, null, 2021
```

I'm not committed to pandas but I do a lot of my data work in pandas and I tried :

```
    df = pd.read_json(json_2020, orient='split')
    data
0   {'name': 'Bob', 'finance': [{'type': 'income',...
1   {'name': 'Alice', 'finance': [{'type': 'income...
```

Is there a way to do this? It doesn't have to be pandas, but I would prefer a native function or library as I'm trying to avoid complex code for each pipeline that I have to deal with.

Edit: to clarify, the complexity is the nested arrays have slightly different elements in different orders.

Comment: What's `real_estate_profits`? Should it be coming from the JSON?

Comment: @richardec that is part of the complexity, the json has different nested elements for different users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You JSON doesn't actually look that complex. I think all you need to do here is load each JSON object as a dataframe, **pivot it**, and then concatenate them:

```
mp = {
    '2020': json_2020,
    '2021': json_2021,
}

dfs = [
    pd.json_normalize(
        json.loads(j)['data'],
        record_path='finance',
        meta='name')
    .pivot(
        index='name',
        columns='type',
        values='value')
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    .assign(year=year)
    
    for year, j in mp.items()
]
    
df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    name    income  real_estate_profits  stock_market_profits  year
0  Alice   90000.0             200000.0                   NaN  2020
1    Bob  100000.0                  NaN                5000.0  2020
2  Alice   75000.0                  NaN                   NaN  2021
3    Bob   90000.0                  NaN                7000.0  2021
```

Comment: Interesting. If I’m getting this data as a stream then I guess I can even skip the four loop and just do merges every time?

Comment: Yes, although it would be better to accumulate the dfs in a list and `concat` them all at the end. Repetitive merges are bad practice and can "fragment" the df.